# How do I break oneline if statement with astyle?

Tags: astyle

Somehow I don't like one line if statements like

```
if (looks_ugly) please_break_this();
```

and want to turn them into this

```
if (looks_ugly)
        please_break_this();
```

Can astyle do that for me? I can't find an appropriate option to astyle.

Answer (score 1):

this will work

```
astyle -J | astyle -xj
```

i.e., first add one line brackets, then remove them. The final output will be formatted automatically.